# tab bar item title programatically not showing in objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I try create tab bar controller programatically, it works but I can not set title to ta bar items. I can not see title when I running my application. My code is here. Please help me, what is the problem?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

myTabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];        
view2Controller = [[testView alloc] init];   
view3Controller = [[testView2 alloc] init];   
view4Controller = [[testView3 alloc] init];   
view5Controller = [[testView4 alloc] init];   
view6Controller = [[testView5 alloc] init];   


myTabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: view2Controller, view3Controller,view4Controller,view5Controller,view6Controller,nil]; 
 UITabBarItem *tabItem = [[[myTabBarController tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:1];
 [tabItem setTitle:@"theTitle"];

[self.view addSubview:myTabBarController.view];    
myTabBarController.selectedIndex=0;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the [title](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/title) of ur viewcontroller in side viewcontroller's viewwillappear/disappear and it will be displayed in ur tabbaritem.

Comment: I was setting it in `viewDidLoad` but it wasn't working, But in `viewWillAppear:` worked fine. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can set the title of `UIViewController`, which reflects when it is pushed in `UINavigationController` or a `UITabBarController`. But you should set the title before putting it inside any of them.

`init` is generally a good place to set the title.

```
- (id)init {
    // ... other code including check for self
    self.title = @"My Title";
    return self;
}
```

Comment: I try this -(id) initWithTabBar {
    if ([self init]) {
        self.title = @"tab1dir";
    }
    return self;
} but not works :S

Comment: Also I try that - (id)init {
    // ... other code including check for self
    self.title = @"My Title";
    return self;
} but still not work

Answer (score 2):

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

        // self.title = @"My Title";
    }

    self.title = @"My Title";
    return self;
}
```

Use above code in every subviews of tabbar controllers.

This may be help.

Answer (score 2):

```
use this code

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title=@"FREE BOOKS";
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"first"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.iphonelife.co.uk/creating-a-uitabbarcontroller-programmatically/) is the tutorial from the scratch which should help you to achieve the exact functionality you want to achieve. Download the source code and run it directly and if title are correct the you can follow the tutorial to get the proper understanding of the flow of UITabBarController.

Comment: in this tutorial -(id) initWithTabBar can show title in tab bar. I try that but not works :S

Comment: I'll suggest you to download the tutorial and compare with your code.

Comment: I can not see downloading link in this tutorial

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tabBar.items?[0].title = "Title"
    }

}
```

OR

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.tabBar.items?[0].title = "Title"

}
```